# How can I build a questionnaire UserControl in XAML whose questions share the same answers?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I'd like to build a `UserControl` to represent a questionnaire, something like that pictured below (ignore the lack of styling).

[image: QuestionnaireControl]

I want to be able to specify the important content in XAML, such as

```xml
<local:QuestionnaireControl>
  <local:QuestionnaireControl.Questions>
    <local:QuestionAndAnswers Number="1" Question="Is this working?" />
    <local:QuestionAndAnswers Number="2" Question="Are these questions sharing answers?" />
  </local:QuestionnaireControl.Questions>
  <local:QuestionnaireControl.Answers>
    <local:Answer Value="0" Text="Yes" />
    <local:Answer Value="1" Text="No" />
    <local:Answer Value="2" Text="Help Me Please" />
  </local:QuestionnaireControl.Answers>
</local:QuestionnaireControl>
```

So I have the following `QuestionnaireControl.xaml`

```cs
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.QuestionnaireControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:QuestionnaireControl, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='{}{0}.'}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question}" Width="220"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <RadioButton
                                        Content="{Binding Text}"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                                        GroupName="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:QuestionAndAnswers}, Path=Question}"
                                        Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                    />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

And the following `QuestionnaireControl.xaml.cs`

```cs
public partial class QuestionnaireControl : UserControl
{
    public QuestionnaireControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
        {
            Questions = new List<QuestionAndAnswers> {
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=1, Question="Do you like pizza?" },
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=2, Question="Can you surf?" },
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=3, Question="Are you funny?" },
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=4, Question="Is Monday your favorite day of the week?" },
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=5, Question="Have you been to Paris?" },
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=6, Question="When sleeping, do you snore?" },
                new QuestionAndAnswers() { Number=7, Question="Could you be living in a dream?" }
            };
            Answers = new List<Answer> {
                new Answer() { Value=1, Text="Yes", IsSelected=false },
                new Answer() { Value=2, Text="No", IsSelected=false },
                new Answer() { Value=3, Text="Sort Of", IsSelected=false },
            };
        }
        else
        {
            Questions = new List<QuestionAndAnswers>();
            Answers = new List<Answer>();
        }

        // Copy Answers to each QuestionAndAnswers.
        foreach (QuestionAndAnswers qa in Questions)
        {
            qa.Answers = new List<Answer>(Answers);
        }
    }

    public List<QuestionAndAnswers> Questions
    {
        get { return (List<QuestionAndAnswers>)GetValue(QuestionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(QuestionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Questions", typeof(List<QuestionAndAnswers>), typeof(QuestionnaireControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<QuestionAndAnswers>()));

    public List<Answer> Answers
    {
        get { return (List<Answer>)GetValue(AnswersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnswersProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnswersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Answers", typeof(List<Answer>), typeof(QuestionnaireControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<Answer>()));
}

public class QuestionAndAnswers
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

With the code above, I'm able to produce the image above of the `QuestionnaireControl` in the Visual Studio designer. But when I actually use the `QuestionnaireControl`, per the example above, the questions are rendered but not the answers. Does anyone know what I need to tweak?

Comment: `// Copy Answers to each QuestionAndAnswers.` part works only once. in design mode it has some data to copy. it doesn't run after answers from `<local:QuestionnaireControl.Answers>` are added after starting the app.

Comment: @ASh How can I get the copying of the Answers to run after the answers from the XAML are added? I tried putting that code into the Loaded callback, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the type of the `Answers` property of the control to `ObservableCollection<Answer>` you could handle its `CollectionChanged` event and copy the answers to each question:

```
public partial class QuestionnaireControl : UserControl
{
    public QuestionnaireControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Questions = new List<QuestionAndAnswers>();
        Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
        Answers.CollectionChanged += Answers_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void Answers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var question in Questions)
        {
            question.Answers = new List<Answer>();
            foreach (var answer in Answers)
            {
                question.Answers.Add(new Answer() { Text = answer.Text, Value = answer.Value, IsSelected = answer.IsSelected });
            }
        }
    }

    public List<QuestionAndAnswers> Questions
    {
        get { return (List<QuestionAndAnswers>)GetValue(QuestionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(QuestionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Questions", typeof(List<QuestionAndAnswers>), typeof(QuestionnaireControl));

    public ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Answer>)GetValue(AnswersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnswersProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnswersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Answers", typeof(ObservableCollection<Answer>), typeof(QuestionnaireControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to copy `Answer` object (`new Answer() {...}`), but detect a moment when it should happens is tricky. `AnswersProperty` changes only 1 time (when new `List<Answer>` is assigned) and then items are added to that List and we have no way to get notification. And we cannot create generic List in xaml (markup limitation). However a known workaround is to create specialized collection derived from generic collection. Here is a complete example (you might want to add INotifyPropertyChnaged implementation to `Answer` and `QuestionAndAnswers` classes):

```
public class QuestionAndAnswers
{
    public QuestionAndAnswers()
    {
        Answers = new ObservableCollection<Answer>();
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Answer> Answers { get; private set; }
}

public class Answer : ICloneable
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class QuestionCollection : List<QuestionAndAnswers>
{
}

public class AnswerCollection : List<Answer>
{
}
```

```
public partial class QuestionnaireControl : UserControl
{
    public QuestionnaireControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public List<QuestionAndAnswers> Questions
    {
        get { return (List<QuestionAndAnswers>) GetValue(QuestionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(QuestionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Questions", typeof (List<QuestionAndAnswers>), typeof (QuestionnaireControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(new List<QuestionAndAnswers>(), QuestionsChangedCallback));

    private static void QuestionsChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q = o as QuestionnaireControl;
        if (q == null)
            return;

        CopyAnswers(q);
    }

    public List<Answer> Answers
    {
        get { return (List<Answer>) GetValue(AnswersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnswersProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnswersProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Answers", typeof(List<Answer>), typeof(QuestionnaireControl),
                new PropertyMetadata(new List<Answer>(), AnswersChangedCallback));

    private static void AnswersChangedCallback(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var q = o as QuestionnaireControl;
        if (q == null)
            return;

        CopyAnswers(q);
    }

    private static void CopyAnswers(QuestionnaireControl q)
    {
        if (q.Answers == null || q.Questions == null)
            return;

        foreach (var question in q.Questions)
        {
            // remove old Answers
            question.Answers.Clear();
            // adding new Answers to each question
            foreach (var answer in q.Answers)
                question.Answers.Add((Answer) answer.Clone());
        }
    }
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfDemos.QuestionnaireControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">    
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat='{}{0}.'}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Question}" Width="220"/>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Answers}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <RadioButton
                                        Content="{Binding Path=Text}"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                                        GroupName="{Binding Path=DataContext.Question, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                                        Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDemos.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfDemos="clr-namespace:WpfDemos"        
        Title="Questionnaire" 
        Height="300" Width="480">
    <wpfDemos:QuestionnaireControl>

        <wpfDemos:QuestionnaireControl.Questions>
            <wpfDemos:QuestionCollection>
                <wpfDemos:QuestionAndAnswers Number="1" Question="Is this working?" />
                <wpfDemos:QuestionAndAnswers Number="2" Question="Are these questions sharing answers?" />
            </wpfDemos:QuestionCollection>
        </wpfDemos:QuestionnaireControl.Questions>

        <wpfDemos:QuestionnaireControl.Answers>
            <wpfDemos:AnswerCollection>
                <wpfDemos:Answer Value="0" Text="Yes" />
                <wpfDemos:Answer Value="1" Text="No" />
                <wpfDemos:Answer Value="2" Text="Help Me Please" />
            </wpfDemos:AnswerCollection>
        </wpfDemos:QuestionnaireControl.Answers>

    </wpfDemos:QuestionnaireControl>
</Window>
```

how it works: `AnswersProperty` and `QuestionsProperty` have property changed callback where we copy answers to question. *And* that callback is triggered because we create new collection (`<wpfDemos:QuestionCollection>`,`<wpfDemos:AnswerCollection>`) :)

Comment: I appreciate the extra code and explanation, but the essential answer was given earlier by `mm8`, so I chose his as the answer. +1 for noticing and fixing the GroupName binding!

Comment: @MichaelRepucci, `Answers.CollectionChanged += Answers_CollectionChanged;` in constructor isn't reliable: if user assign new collection to public `Answers` property, Questions won't be updated and `Answers_CollectionChanged` won't trigger anymore

Answer (score 0):

Code which copies answer options for each question works incorrectly. For once it runs only once in constructor and not after answers are added. Additionally it doesn't create new instances of `Answer` objects and as result all questions keep  the same references and when first option is selected for one question, it is immediately selected for all others. Each question need its own set of answers:

```
public class QuestionAndAnswers
{
    public QuestionAndAnswers()
    {
       Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

```
<local:QuestionnaireControl>
  <local:QuestionnaireControl.Questions>

    <local:QuestionAndAnswers Number="1" Question="Is this working?">
      <local:QuestionAndAnswers.Answers>
       <local:Answer Value="0" Text="Yes" />
       <local:Answer Value="1" Text="No" IsSelected="true"/>
       <local:Answer Value="2" Text="Help Me Please" />
      </local:QuestionAndAnswers.Answers>
    </local:QuestionAndAnswers>

    <local:QuestionAndAnswers Number="2" Question="Are these questions sharing answers?">
      <local:QuestionAndAnswers.Answers>
       <local:Answer Value="0" Text="Yes" IsSelected="true"/>
       <local:Answer Value="1" Text="No" />
       <local:Answer Value="2" Text="Help Me Please" />
      </local:QuestionAndAnswers.Answers>
    </local:QuestionAndAnswers>

  </local:QuestionnaireControl.Questions>
</local:QuestionnaireControl>
```

Comment: I explicitly want to avoid the duplication of the answers on each question in the XAML, as that could easily lead to errors.

Comment: @MichaelRepucci, see another answer. Note that I don't have design time data set in .ctor, because designer should display real data from Question and Answers list. Also note changes in control xaml (`GroupName` binding in particular)

Comment: @MichaelRepucci, can you please give any feedback regrading alternative solution I posted?

Comment: sorry, have a million things to do, and this is just one. I should be able to get back to this before the end of the week. Thanks for the proposed solutions!